# How to remove tags from data in the database?

Tags: php

So I have inserted data in the database that contains `\n` and `\t`. How can I display on the webpage with PHP without `\n` and `\t` appearing on the data to be displayed?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please post the code and where it fails. Why insert `\n` and `\t` anyway if you don't need them? Also: no caps, please

Comment: After reading this book, you’ll be able to do a whole lot more. –Dirk Schreckmann, JavaRanch Sheriff and Journal Editor

Let Beginning JSP 2 be your guide as you begin using JSP. This comprehensive guide starts by steering you through your first JSP application. It reviews HTML, and provides you with a useful overview of JSP. You’ll then be ready to start learning one of the core techniques in JSP: pulling data from a database and working with that data.

When  i want to display these two paragraphs separately its not working and it displays /n and /t within the content displayed

Answer (score 0):

use preg_split

```
$output = preg_split( "/ (/n|/t) /", $input );
```

Comment: its not working,am trying to display two paragraphs from database results but the output just contains \n and \t no separate paragraphs

Comment: better you have to use  explode like as follow

Answer (score 0):

use explode
if consider your answer from db is

```
$input="hai /n hello /t";
$output1=explode('/n',$input);
$output=explode('/t',$output1);
```

it's working if result within foreach you may add this line into foreach()

Answer (score 0):

item = item.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');